# How to turn on Unity HUD

Tags: unity, hud

I have Ubuntu 12.10 (upgraded from Lubuntu).  According to Synaptic, I have Unity installed.  How do I turn on the HUD?

Comment: Just tap the ALT key and it appears.

Answer (score 3):

Tapping the ALT key activates it for me.